# Typescript error in Promise.then callback

Tags: typescript, promise

What is the problem and how can i solve it ?

```js
function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    return p.then(result => {
        if (result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
}
/**
Argument of type '(result: boolean) => false | Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean) => void | PromiseLike<void>'. 
Type 'false | Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'. 
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'.
*/
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2ACgJQBcMACgE7oC2qIApgDwBu6qAJjAD4wBG66ANjWAQAfDADeAWABQMWTAHIYABxgBeEuSq0AdKRoh%20DGjjjA%20tPAG5pcmHuQJSWJduQALGhBx6QCPotVRSRlbOVQ4GG99PwDVdVNzGjxxG1C0%200csBNprELSAX1T0mgcnDUpqGl19Q2MrIph8%20ql8oA)

If I write like this, there is no error

```js
function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    return p.then(result => {
        if (result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return Promise.resolve().then();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback needs to be `async`:

```
async function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    return p.then(async result => { // Added async
        if (result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thinks，This can fix the error, But I am still confused，If I do not return an boolean, There is no error even without async, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your callback into an `async` function like this.

```
return p.then(async
```

But your definition of `a()` is already an `async` function. So there is no need for the `.then()` construct at all.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
async function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    const p = Promise.resolve(false);
    const result = await p;
    
    if (result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Thinks, If I don't use async/await, How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use async/await, you can just tell the compiler what generic type to use for `then`, like this:

```
async function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    return p.then<void | boolean>(result => {
        if (result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change would be to just return `undefined` instead of `Promise.resolve()` or use async/await as others have suggested.

```
async function a(): Promise<void | boolean> {
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    return p.then(async result => { // Added async
        if (result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return; // or return undefined
    });
}
```